# Create a circle in R, and plot it in a shapefile

Tags: shapefile, r, sf

I want to plot a circle with a radius of 5 miles around a hospital in Massachusetts. I was using some previous answers found here, but it is not working. st_buffer shows an error.

```
library(sp)
library(rgdal)
library(sf)

# Getting data:
download.file('http://download.massgis.digital.mass.gov/shapefiles/state/zipcodes_nt.zip',
              f <- tempfile(), mode='wb')
unzip(f, exdir=tempdir())
p <- readOGR(file.path(tempdir(), 'ZIPCODES_NT_POLY.shp'))
# location of hospital.
lon <- -71.06
lat <- 42.36

# defining the hospital location
dub <- st_point(x = c(lon, lat), dim = "XYZ")
dub <- dub %>% st_sfc(crs = 4326)
m5 <- set_units(8.04672, km) %>% set_units(m)
dub_buffer <-  st_buffer(dub, m5)
plot(p)
plot(dub_buffer, add=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with [@mweber](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/17969/mweber). If you are happy with UTM 19N, EPSG:32619 will do.

```
library(sp)
library(rgdal)
library(sf)
library(units)

# Getting data:
download.file('http://download.massgis.digital.mass.gov/shapefiles/state/zipcodes_nt.zip',
              f <- tempfile(), mode='wb')
unzip(f, exdir=tempdir())
p <- readOGR(file.path(tempdir(), 'ZIPCODES_NT_POLY.shp'))
# location of hospital.
lon <- -71.06
lat <- 42.36

# defining the hospital location
dub <- st_point(x = c(lon, lat), dim = "XYZ")
dub <- dub %>% st_sfc(crs = 32619)
m5 <- units::set_units(8.04672, km)
dub_buffer <-  st_buffer(dub, m5)
plot(p)
plot(dub_buffer, add=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you need to project `dub`, your point for hospital - you've set its crs as geographic coordinates.  Your code works for me if you add this line prior to the set_units line:

`dub <- st_transform(dub, crs=5070)`

Any projected crs using meters will do.